# Clang linebreak after access modifier

Tags: c++, class, clang-format

I can't find a configuration for the linebreak behaviour after access modifiers.
(But without setting MaxEmptyLinesToKeep to 0)
(To remove the linebreak after an access modifier change)
I have my current clang configuration like this:

```
Language: Cpp
CompactNamespaces: false
FixNamespaceComments: false
Cpp11BracedListStyle: true
NamespaceIndentation: All
PointerAlignment: Right
SortIncludes: false
SpacesInParentheses: false
SpaceInEmptyParentheses: false
SpaceAfterTemplateKeyword: false
SortUsingDeclarations: false
SpaceBeforeAssignmentOperators: true
SpaceBeforeCtorInitializerColon: true
SpaceBeforeInheritanceColon: true
IndentWidth: 4
TabWidth: 4
ColumnLimit: 0
AccessModifierOffset: -1
UseTab: true
MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 2
BreakBeforeBraces: Allman
AlignConsecutiveAssignments: true
AlignConsecutiveDeclarations: true
AlignEscapedNewlines: Right 
KeepEmptyLinesAtTheStartOfBlocks: false
AllowShortFunctionsOnASingleLine: None 
BraceWrapping:
  AfterFunction: true
  AfterClass: true
  AfterStruct: true    
  AfterControlStatement: true  
  AfterEnum: true 
  AfterUnion: true
  AfterExternBlock: true
  AfterNamespace: true    
  AfterUnion: true    
  BeforeCatch: true
  BeforeElse: true
  SplitEmptyFunction: true
  SplitEmptyRecord: true
  IndentBraces: false
BreakBeforeBraces: Custom
```

**Example:**
At the moment clang produces:

```
class Test
{
 public:
   int test();

 private:
   int m_test;
}
```

But i want it to remove the linebreak so that it becomes:

```
class Test
{
 public:
   int test();
 private:
   int m_test;
}
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I use "MaxEmptyLinesToKeep: 0" which has the strange behavior that the empty line gets removed if it exists BUT the empty line is *added* when it doesn't exist. So if I format the code once, it changes. A second time formating the code changes it back to the original. Very strange behavior.

Comment: No sadly i never found a solution for that :/